# Using mysql_num_rows with multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the code I've started with:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM apis_hashes_a", $link);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

What I need to do is to get the total sum of all rows for all tables that start with `apis_hashes_`.

There are tons of tables and new ones are being added all the time, but all of these tables start with `apis_hashes_` at the beginning.  Is this something that would be possible to do or do I have to list every table individually in the PHP code?

Comment: What do you need? Total sum of all fields and rows for all the tables from name array like spreadsheet? OR find the list of tables in database?

Comment: Why are you creating so many tables? Sounds like there are othe problems here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUST use `SUM()` IN SQL.Use the code below

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) as score
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE SCHEMA = '{your_db_name}'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$total_rows = $row['score'];
}
echo $total_rows;
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

The sql:

```
show tables like 'apis_hashes_%'
```

will return the list of all your tables, then you need loop thru all the names of the tables with the mysql `sum()` function.